# get_user_model() vs settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL usage

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to Django and I am following a video tutorial to learn django. I am trying to understand get_user_model() and setting.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
my directory looks like below:

```
| simplesocial
   | accounts
   |  | models.py
   |  | views.py
   |  | forms.py
   | 
   | simplesocial
      |settings.py
```

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth
from simplesocial import settings
# Create your models here.


class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return '@{}'.format(self.username)
```

```
#forms.py

from django.forms import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from simplesocial import settings


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        fields = ('username', 'email')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

I am getting below error

```
ERRORS:
accounts.User.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

Since I have a custom user model to be used. What am I doing wrong. If I replace settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL with get_user_model() will it use my custom User class? I could not understand how get_user_model() works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Replacing,

```
from simplesocial import settings
```

with

```
from django.conf import settings
```

About get_user_model,

lets say you like to create a User model containing fields like username, password, etc.
But this model is already created by django which is get_user_model which contains all 
fields which a User Model may require. So you just need to import it in your file. So, in order to save your time avoid making the same model from scratch(beginning).

About AUTH_USER_MODEL,

mainly use when you are working on custom model (by mentioning this in settings.py file
we tell django that instead of using default django model use the custom model created by us.

for more information visit to django documentation,
link, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/